# Embed resque-web frontend in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I'm using resque web front end to manage my background jobs. I'm wondering if someone know how I can embed this front end inside my main layout. I want to use my application layout and keep my html header.

I'm actually mount resque as a Rails rack.

```
mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/resque"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the resque Gem

```
resque / lib / resque / server /
```

There is a view and public folder you could directly modify them or These views files are used by a sinatra app which is called in

```
resque/lib/resque/server.rb
```

You could monkey patch that Server class(Sinatra App) to use your own views.